# Get current URL outside FancyBox modal

Tags: php, fancybox

I'd like to get the current URL of the page I'm on and not the one that's being loaded within a FancyBox modal with PHP.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gives me the URL of the page that's being loaded within the FancyBox modal.

Example:

While I'm a `a.php`, I'd like to click a link that opens a modal window with `b.php` loaded and to have a PHP code within `b.php` to say that I'm from `a.php`, not from `b.php` (which now happens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use PHP. You need to use javascript. In `b.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var parentURL = window.parent.location.href
    alert(parentURL);

</script>
```

If you really need the know the URL of `a.php` in your PHP code, consider passing it as GET parameter when opening `b.php` page. So, in `a.php` your link to `b.php` will be something as:

```
<?php $myURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>

<a href="b.php?parent=<?php echo urlencode($myURL) ?>">Open B</a>
```

And then, in `b.php`:

```
$parentURL = $_GET['parent'];
```